# Calling a macro on a macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm trying to write a Clojure macro that creates a prefix notation list for evaluation from a simple infix notation list, say `(2 * 3 + 4 * 2)` to an evaluated`(+ (* 2 3) (*4 2))` (resulting in 14 being returned).

I have written the following code:

```
(defmacro infix [op inlist]
  (let [[i1 i2 & i3] inlist
        last-group? (nil? (second i3))]  

    (if last-group?
      `(if (= ~op ~i2)
        (~i2 ~i1 ~(first i3)) ; return unevaluated prefix list
        (~i1 ~i2 ~(first i3))) ; return unevaluated infix list
      `(if (= ~op ~i2)
         ; recur with prefix list in i1 position
         (infix ~op ~(conj (rest i3) (list i2 i1 (first i3)) ))
         ; return as list: i1 and i2, recur i3 (probably wrong)
         (~i1 ~i2 (infix ~op ~i3))
         ))))
```

With the intention of enforcing operator precedence by calling the macro recursively with different `op` (operator function) parameters:

```
(infix + (infix * (2 * 3 + 4 * 2)))
```

Above, I'm just using it with two `*` and `+`, but ultimately I'd want to call the macro for all (or at least for the sake of [this exercise](http://www.braveclojure.com/read-and-eval/#Exercises), / * + -) operators.

When I execute the above nested macro call, I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'cbat.ch7.ex2/infix, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4661580047453041691.clj:1:1)
```

Calling the macro for a single operator and a list of the same operator (i.e. `(infix * (2 * 3 * 4))`) works as expected. If I call the macro with a single `(i1 i2 i3)` list, if `op` differs from `i2`, it tries to (understandably) return the unevaluated infix list with the error:

```
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  cbat.ch7.ex2/eval3003 (form-init4661580047453041691.clj:1)
```

I was hoping calling the macro recursively would mean that I could process the unevaluated infix list before the entire line was evaluated, but this doesn't seem to work.

---

I'm pretty sure the else branch of the latter, inner `if` (i.e. `(~i1 ~i2 (infix ~op ~i3))`) is incorrect and I may just need the inner infix call, but I'm more concerned with getting the nested macro calls for the different operators working prior to evaluation.

I know that this isn't the usual way of converting infix to prefix notation, and have since found out about [Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), but please could someone kindly enlighten me as to:

1. whether such nested macro calls are possible?
2. whether my logic is reasonable, and not too far from a solution? If so...
3. ... what changes I need to make to get things running?

I'm really focused on learning Clojure, so any thorough explanation (where possible) will be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest macro calls as this code demonstrates:

```
(defmacro mac [tag & forms]
  `(do
     (println "mac - enter" ~tag)
     ~@forms
     (println "mac - exit " ~tag)))

(mac :a
  (doseq [i (range 3)]
    (mac :b (println i))))

mac - enter :a
mac - enter :b
0
mac - exit  :b
mac - enter :b
1
mac - exit  :b
mac - enter :b
2
mac - exit  :b
mac - exit  :a
```

You can also make recursive macro calls as this shows:

```
(defmacro macr [n]
  (if (zero? n)
    1
    `(* ~n (macr ~(dec n)))))

(macr 5)   => 120
```

Without delving too deep into your particular implementation, I would suggest 2 points:

1. At least to start, keep your forms as simple as possible. This means only forms like `(2 + 3)`. And especially don't force the macro to figure out operator precedence in the early versions (or ever!).
2. Macros are ***almost never*** necessary, and it is unfortunate IMHO that they are somewhat "over-hyped" when learning Clojure & other lisps. I would suggest you don't even think about them for the first year or two, as they are more brittle than functions and less powerful in important ways (you can't pass a macro into a function, for example).

### Update

Whenever you want to write something complicated (a macro definitely qualifies!), start small and
build it up one step at a time.  Using [the lein-test-refresh plugin](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh) and [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) definitely help
here.

First, make the simplest possible macro and observe its behavior:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn infix-fn [[a op b]]
  (spyx a)
  (spyx op)
  (spyx b)
  )

(defmacro infix [form]
  (infix-fn form))

(infix (2 + 3))

a => 2
op => +
b => 3
```

For many macros, it is helpfully to send the marcro args to a helper function like `infix-fn`. The
`spyx` helps us by printing the symbol and its value.  At this point, we can simply re-order the
args into prefix notation and away we go:

```
(defn infix-fn [[a op b]] (list op a b))

(defmacro infix [form] (infix-fn form))

(deftest master
  (is= 5 (infix (2 + 3)))
  (is= 6 (infix (2 * 3))))
```

What if we have a recursive tree structure?  Check if we need to recurse in `infix-fn`:

```
(declare infix-fn)

(defn simplify [arg]
  (if (list? arg)
    (infix-fn arg)
    arg))

(defn infix-fn [[a op b]]
  (list op (simplify a) (simplify b)))

(is= 7 (infix ((2 * 2) + 3)))
(is= 9 (infix ((1 + 2) * 3)))


(is= 35 (infix ((2 + 3) * (3 + 4))))
(is= 26 (infix ((2 * 3) + (4 * 5))))
```

I would not want to add in the complication of operator precedence.  If absolutely necessary, I
would not code it up myself but would use [the excellent Instaparse library](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) for that purpose.

Comment: Alan, thanks for the answer, appreciated. I'd like to say that this was an early version, but I've been trying to do this for weeks. As you suggested, I've attempted to simplify things eliminating functionality for everything but three symbol forms, but still getting the ``java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro`` error. Could you be so kind as to provide some implementation specific pointers please?

Comment: Alan, thanks again - as I don't really have a local group of Clojurists to discuss with, this level of detail is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Be sure to also join the Clojure Google Group:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure

Answer (score 2):

expansion of your call would give you a clue:

```
(if (= + *) 
  (* infix (2 * 3 + 4 * 2)) 
  (infix * (2 * 3 + 4 * 2)))
```

You've got the wrong presumption that the argument of macro would be expanded before the macro itself, i guess. But in fact in this one: `(~i2 ~i1 ~(first i3))` `i1` is still `infix` symbol. As far as i can see, the solution is to add some new condition branch, treating `infix` form some special way.